Are there still advantages of the data-flow diagram in a world of SysML and UML?
I recall some criticizing structured analysis as something outdated, but it seems that it is still in use today at least with DFDs. A company who claims to be agile in its ways was using a tool called PyTM for threat modeling for example, and that tool was a tool that generated DFDs.
I suppose if one were to create the equivalent of a DFD diagram, it might be a UML activity diagram, but after trying so many tools for SysML and UML in the past, I began to wonder if just simple circles and arrows and boxes representing data stores are the way to go after all. And with the upcoming SysML v2, it seems that users are in for major changes which practically have no tooling support.
DFDs seem to align with how people draw things on white boards. It may be that something as old as DFDs just might be modern after all. Are agile organizations big on DFDs?

See How to model data flow between components in UML, and my answer to that question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/400785.   My opinion about that is still the same: it is IMHO a big mistake that DFDs are so much underrepresented in UML

Eventmodeling is gaining traction. Doing that and you won’t need anything else.

"A company who claims to be agile in its ways" that seems completely unrelated to the rest of the question. Agile doesn't mean "don't design, just code", so using design tools/systems/methodologies isn't contrary to being/doing "Agile".

@JoryGeerts You’re right on that; I expressed myself a bit vaguely with that comment. What I was trying to say was the company having agile practices, but using structured analysis notation such as DFDs. They definitely had design in their process, but it had surprised me that DFDs were being used by a startup. I guess the real message is, use the tool or notation to get the job done and communicate a design that is understandable, regardless of notation even if it came from pre-agile, OO days. After all, we still see boxes and line diagrams all the time.

Data Flow Diagrams remain popular. So popular that when people look at class diagrams for the first time you have to explain to them that the arrows don’t point in the direction of data flow (those point to dependencies; showing what it knows about).
Data flow diagrams show what goes in where, where it comes out, and what it does along the way. It’s a good way to illustrate a system at a high level that makes it easy to show the major components and what they are for.
But it’s not strictly an alternative to UML. Data flow diagrams have become part of uml. UML formalizes many kinds of diagrams. But few people have patience for that formality and it usually just ends up being labeled boxes and labeled arrows. Which is fine if you explain them well. I'll take a good explanation over strict adherence to formalism any day.

"DFDs have become part of UML" - too late, too badly named, advertised far too poorly, which leads to bad tool support and people hesitating to use them.

I could imagine doing something like an activity diagram with pins and object flows and decompose them into structured activity diagrams like in DFDs. Then I could allocate those activities to classes. This would be a variant of Hassan Gomaas “Ada based design method for real time systems (ADARTS)”. He starts with DFDs and then creates tasks diagrams followed by Ada packages and their allocations.

Structured analysis
Structured analysis, pioneered by Tom DeMarco (Yourdon Inc.) & Larry Constantine, or Chris Gane & Trish Sarson, and a couple of other methodologists, dates back to the 1970s. Three core techniques of this method are:

Top down analysis,  breaking down a system into smaller parts
Modeling the data flows between the system parts or with external "entities"
Maintaining in parallel to the data flow a comprehensive data dictionary. At the end of the analysis,  you could just use it to implement your database,  if you didn't already use ERD which was also a technique born in the 70s.

Structured analysis was state of the art and helped to make really complex systems methodically.  I was myself a big fan,  and my first project as an intern was to write a DFD modeling tool. However, it leads mechanically to a big upfront design.
Using DFD independently from SA
As many diagramming technique, you can use the DFD diagramming technique in your own way, as suits your needs.  You can certainly  use it to sketch easily some quick diagrams to support discussions in an agile team.
However, DFD is build on separating data (the arrows) from the processes (the boxes or circles). This is useful for designing databases.  But nowadays we tend to use objects, which are data + behaviours, so the distinction becomes more fuzzy.
On top of that, DFDs are not standardised. There are at least 2 main notations,  but many more variants.  This can create confusion and ambiguity.  Last but not least, the flows in these diagrams are always simple: you can for example not show that data may be dispatched between several processes,  or that several processes run in parallel with the same data.
More modern alternatives
If your problem/design is simple enough for being modelled with a few circles and lines with DFDs, chances are that you can as easily model them with a few rounded rectangles and lines in activity diagrams.
Activity diagrams have a higher standardization than DFDs.  there is only one notation and it allows a high degree of accuracy when needed.  The key features are:

activities correspond to processes
flow between actions can be either control flow (without data) or object flows
datastores correspond To datastores/sources/sink
there are no "external entities" but these can easily be emulated with swimmlaneg, and sterotypes/symbol on some program activity
if needed,  you can show filtering and conditional routing, timeouts,  parallel flows, etc.

There is no top-down incentive. While DFDs often rely on decimal hierarchical numbering of the processes and the diagrams,  in UML diagrams are not supposed to be a single complete truth.  They are supposed to show only a selected set of elements useful for the discussion.
Another candidates for data flows is BPMN  which as process modeling notation is very appropriate for showing flows, including of information.  It has the advantage of being standardised as well.  A study nevertheless found out that it is more complex to understand for laypersons than equivalent activity diagrams, due to the higher number of symbols required by BPMN.
What is more agile?
We must not confuse the tools with the way the tools are used. It is true that DFDs are closely linked to SA and UML is methodology neutral (just a notational language).  Some agilists promoted activity diagrams on the whiteboard in an agile fashion.
But in the end, both tools can be used in an agile context, and in a light and easy way (You don't have to use all the bells and whistles of UML, just the ones that help you).  I can only recommend the more standardised technique.

The comment on top down design I don’t quite get since usually we have very little information at the start. We just have external things and a big circle in the middle and we go about refining as we get more information. That seems agile to me, or is there another take on that?

To be honest, I don't like the attempt to replace DFDs by activity diagrams. ADs have a different intention, a different semantics, and "conditional routing" is something I usually don't want to see in a DFD. And I don't buy the "DFD is an upfront-analysis tool" argument - DFDs can be scaled up and down to different levels of abstraction, it can be used in agile approaches as well as for upfront-analysis, and they are not better or worse suited for agility than every other kind of higher-level design diagram.

@DocBrown I hear what you say, but DFD stands for Data Flow Diagram. Activity diagrams are meant to model flows, which can be Object Flows (object=not just flat data but data and behavior) and control flows. It provides all the semantics of dfd, with the exception of the external entities, which you could emulate through swim lanes or a stereotyped proforma action if absolutely needed. The leading books about DFDs are all from the 70s, at best the 80s. the circles (your don/de marco) or the rounded boxes (gane&sarson) represent "processe" so in theory activities although in practice often

modules. But I understand that it can be comfortable to continue using them.

@Passeris my point here is that dfd are not more agile than activity diagrams. And I just add the context: the methodologies that lead to the emergence of DFDs are based on a top down decomposition of a "context"/"level 0" diagram showing entry and exit flow in a system, and then decompose the system into smaller parts and show also the flows at that lower level. If you read the main pioneers, i.e. Tom DeMarco from Yourdon Inc. and Gane&Sarson, you'll find out that they describe not only top down but also promote an upfront analysis. At the time they wrote (end of 70s) this was

considered as the proper approach and agile was not yet born, although there were already the prémisses of iterations.  On the other side UML which is often accused to be to rigid was also successfully used in agile approaches, either directly, or indirectly via "robustness diagrams"

Ok, I admit, after informing myself a lttle bit more about Activity diagrams for object flows, I think you are right, they can be used to express the semantics of DFDs (I guess this was introduced in UML 2,0, in UML 1.x activity diagrams were mostly state machines). Still, whereever you find an introduction to Activity  diagrams, the primary focus is always on control flow (like here in Wikipedia, and it is poorly explained that an AD can be used differently.

@DocBrown Here I admit you are right.  Very often the activity diagrams on the net show examples about control flow and are used as a kind of more modern flow chart.  While this is not intrinsically wrong,  it's not the only use case.  With the object flows one can nicely model data flows, even giving better visibility (if desired) to the objects that are flowing.  This can even help to give a functional flavour if need be.

@Christophe, I agree, and even in the text “A Practical Guide to SysML”, there is a whole chapter dedicated to “Modeling flow-based behavior with Activity Diagrams”.  However, as DocBrown points out, with the merge nodes and paths, it is easy to get into control flow aspects. It would be interesting to see how far one could get modeling pure data-flow while avoiding the control flow parts. Even if one did, wouldn’t that just be like a Composite Structure Diagram in the end where there are classes and parts linked via ports?

@Passeris: "It would be interesting to see how far one could get modeling pure data-flow while avoiding the control flow parts. ". Well, the german software engineer made a full programming model of it, more than 10 years ago, which he called Flow Design

@Passeris whatever the notation, it may not prevent modelers from modeling what they want. Indeed, one could very well mix control flow and object flow. In the other side, from time to time dfd modelers are stuck because some kind of data goes to one process whereas another should go elsewhere. If this is something really needed, why for it it. The split andmerge nodes have also a precise semantic When used for object flow.  As said, a minimum of trust is needed here. because modelers could also misuse dfds
